# ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've a SQL query where if output is NULL it should not send warning .

```
l_sup_id    NUMBER;

begin

SELECT  per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id
    INTO  l_sup_id
FROM    per_all_assignments_f
WHERE   person_id = p_person_id
    AND     trunc (sysdate) BETWEEN effective_start_date
                    AND     effective_end_date
    AND     primary_flag = 'Y';

elsif (p_person_type = 'APPRAISER' AND  l_sup_id IS NOT NULL) then
        hr_utility.set_message(801, 'HR_51888_APR_APPRAISER_NULL');
        hr_utility.raise_error;
end if;
```

Whenever l_sup_id is null according to logic

```
  hr_utility.set_message(801, 'HR_51888_APR_APPRAISER_NULL');
```

should not be executed

But whenever l_sup_id is null I am getting

> ORA-01403: no data found

error in logs

If l_sup_id is not null application working is fine

Comment: Where is the if corresponding to your elsif in the middle of your code?

Comment: `if (p_person_id is NULL) then
 if p_person_type = 'APPRAISEE' then
           hr_utility.set_message(801, 'HR_51887_APR_APPRAISEE_NULL');
           hr_utility.raise_error;
 elsif (p_person_type = 'APPRAISER' AND  l_sup_id IS NOT NULL) then
  hr_utility.set_message(801, 'HR_51888_APR_APPRAISER_NULL');
           hr_utility.raise_error;
   end if;
   end if;`

Comment: `NO_DATA_FOUND` error is raised in your **SELECT .. INTO** statement. So, it never goes to the next line i.e. your **IF-ELSE** construct.

Comment: Here `SELECT  per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id
 INTO  l_sup_id` is getting null value . I am manually setting `supervisor_id` to null . So logically there should not be no data found error

Comment: To keep it simple.. try `SELECT  MAX(per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id)
    INTO  l_sup_id` (Unless, you don't have any other non-aggregated column) !! Other wise, the error says, no rows are qualified for your search... That doesnt mean, it returns null. It returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests its pointing to NO DATA for the condition, to handle that you need to use "Exception Handling", Please see the code for the changes,

```
declare
l_sup_id    NUMBER;

begin

SELECT  per_all_assignments_f.supervisor_id
    INTO  l_sup_id
FROM    per_all_assignments_f
WHERE   person_id = p_person_id
    AND     trunc (sysdate) BETWEEN effective_start_date
                    AND     effective_end_date
    AND     primary_flag = 'Y';

elsif (p_person_type = 'APPRAISER' AND  l_sup_id IS NOT NULL) then
        hr_utility.set_message(801, 'HR_51888_APR_APPRAISER_NULL');
        hr_utility.raise_error;
end if;
--changes start
exception
when no_Data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('No data exists for lsup '|| l_sup_id)

--changes end
end;
```

**Edit:**

```
   SQL> SELECT * FROM TESTEMP WHERE EMPNO=6677;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      6677 JUPITER    CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL>
SQL>  declare
  2   l_count number;
  3   begin
  4   select comm into l_count from testemp where empno=6677 ;
  5   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lcount is'||l_count);
  6   if (l_count IS NULL) then
  7   dbms_output.put_line('no data');
  8   else
  9   dbms_output.put_line('data');
 10   end if;
 11   end;
 12  /

lcount is
no data

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Your condition wont go into the if at all if you compare to NULL or how ever you want to use it according to your specification

Comment: This solution won't help when. l_sup_id is null why no data found error is coming that is my question . Can you help in this regard

Comment: Please see the edit section of answer to handle null

Answer (score 0):

From documentation,

> **NO_DATA_FOUND**
>
> A SELECT INTO statement returns no rows, or your program references a
>   deleted element in a nested table or an uninitialized element in an
>   index-by table.

In your PL/SQL code, the **SELECT .. INTO** statement returns no rows, thus it raises **NO_DATA_FOUND** error. It never goes to the next line, i.e. your `IF-ELSE` construct.

If you want to continue the operation, then you need to handle the **EXCEPTION** gracefully.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    o_ename emp.ename%TYPE;
  3    i_empno emp.empno%TYPE;
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT ename INTO o_ename FROM emp WHERE empno = i_empno;
  6    -- Handle no_data_found
  7  EXCEPTION
  8  WHEN no_data_found THEN
  9    -- do something
 10    dbms_output.put_line('No records found for employee no '|| i_empno);
 11  END;
 12  /
No records found for employee no

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses.
Instead of plain sql I created the following cursor

```
cursor csr_supervisor_id 
                    is
        SELECT  supervisor_id
        FROM    per_all_assignments_f
        WHERE   person_id = p_person_id
            AND     trunc (sysdate) BETWEEN effective_start_date
                    AND     effective_end_date
            AND     primary_flag = 'Y';
```

and fetched it in l_sup_id

```
open csr_supervisor_id;
fetch csr_supervisor_id into l_sup_id;
```

Now no data received error is not coming.